# Different flexbox alignment on small screen for 3 divs

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, flexbox

Basically I need 3 divs to align on small width (<576px) like in the top of image below and on rest of the widths (>576px) like in the bottom on the image below.

[image]

How it can be achieved with bootstrap flexbox classes?

I'm assuming base set is:

```
<div class="d-flex">
  <div>A</div>
  <div>B</div>
  <div>C</div>
</div>
```

I don't see `.column` and `.row` classes being used because `A` and `B` don't share same div on small and large screens... experimented with differnt classes with no success.

Comment: Image link does not load. But it's better to show what you have used so that users can improvise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the alignment top of the image. Use align-content utilities on flexbox containers to align flex items together on the cross axis. You can choose

```
<div class="d-flex align-content-start flex-wrap">...</div>
```

for the content top of the image and for bottom you can choose

```
<div class="d-flex align-content-end flex-wrap">...</div>
```

Here, I am assuming that image would be in different `<div>` and For the responsive behaviour you can use .order classes